# HTML not interpreted on droppages

Tags: html, hosting, dropbox

When trying to publish a website using [droppages.com](http://droppages.com/) (which basically works fine), I encountered the problem that - on the "live" website - it is not interpreted as HTML, but the code is shown in a `pre` instead.

Do you have any ideas why that could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Droppages doesn't only interpret HTML, but also Markdown. And in markdown, you define a code snippet (which means a `<pre>` in HTML) by simply intending it.

If the file on droppages is minified (= all empty lines and intendations removed), that's no longer a problem.